# Alertdialog of background application on current screen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-activity

If an application is in the background, and on some event it displays a Alertdialog. The dialog is shown within the application's activity. However, i want it to be displayed on whatever screen the user is currently on. 
So if the user is on the homescreen, and the application in the background, the pop up of should be shown on the homescreen.'
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Since an alert dialog depends on a context and since your activity is in the background (so potentially destroyed by the system) I don't think you can do that. Besides, displaying alert dialogs which are not related to the current activity might be confusing for the user. A better approach would be to use status bar notifications

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1):

If an *activity* is in the background, it's paused. If you're running some background task in the activity on a separate thread, you should probably move that work to a service. To alert the user of things happening in the background, use a notification.

This is for *your* benefit, as well as the user's. If you shove your activity to the foreground while the user is doing something else, the user is *not* going to like your application. It may or may not work, but it's against the Android [Design Guide guidelines for notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html).

There is a setFullScreenIntent() you can use to send an Intent out of a PendingIntent instead of posting a notification, but it's meant for situations such as phone calls.

Comment: Actually the alert IS supposed to be for an incoming phone call of some sort. I just wanted this as a temporary solution. And yes, i do intend to put the task in a service. Thanks.